# Handle wildcards matching no file in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards, array

I am trying to read files from a directory into an array but even when the file doesn't exist, it is saved into the array. I want to exclude the file name if it doesn't exist.

```
a=(/tmp/nofileexists) && echo ${#a[@]} && echo ${a[@]}
1
/tmp/nofileexists
```

The path may contain a wild card.

```
a=(/tmp/nofileexists*.pdf) && echo ${#a[@]} && echo ${a[@]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `nullglob` for `bash` return empty string when file name expansion fail :

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ a=(/tmp/nofileexists*.pdf) && echo ${#a[@]} && echo ${a[@]}
0
<blank line>
```

Or using `failglob` to report error:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ a=(/tmp/nofileexists*.pdf) && echo ${#a[@]} && echo ${a[@]}
bash: no match: /tmp/nofileexists*.pdf
```